# REST API Resource Models

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest

I'm developing a REST API in C# and I have a question about the best way to represent a resource.

What's the best practice for fields of a resource that may not be critical and are data heavy.

Will use "Company" as an example.

*Company*

- Name
- Type
- Address
- Social

Social

- Twitter
- Facebood
- Google Plus
- Email
- PhoneNumber

**Approach #1**

Expose a "Fields" parameter that allows the developer to specify which fields they want returned.

EG: Get Company?Fields="Name,Type,Address"

**Approach #2**

We decide which fields of each resource to return by default. Developers have to "Opt-In" to have those fields returned.

EG:

Company resource now looks like

*Company*

- Name
- Type
- Address

Only way to get a company's social data is then
GET Company?Include="Social"

**Approach #3**

Don't have the field returned in the resource but have it accessible as a sub-resource.

GET Company/{Id}/Social

Comment: Well, you could look at real world critical/transactional implementations - e.g. [Paypal REST](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) and see the pattern of some specific `response` to a request and HATEOAS for possible "options" or "next steps" for the client to choose whatever it wants to (or must) do (next)....Hth...

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you want your API used. Remember, you're exposing behavior, not your database. I do believe that #1 and #3 are best practices and you should use a combination of both. It's referenced in this article [here](http://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/).

Questions I would ask myself:

How often would these fields be needed? 
Can you picture someone making use of a company without it's social fields?

Are the social fields in the same table?
Is the lookup for those fields expensive? 
How would that affect my indexes?

Whatever you do, make sure you don't over complicate things by exposing too much functionality. I tried this before and it just ended up being a headache.

Comment: Thanks That makes sense.

So I should return it in the resource but also have it accessible as a sub-resource. Then allow the user to filter it out using the fields parameters.